# Can I have SoapUI write results to a DB

Tags: soapui

I like to have all my automation write to a simple 3 table DB to show results in a dashboard.  I typically create my own web service test tools but I like soapUI features.  Can I have soap UI write results out to a format of my choosing to a mysql DB?

Has anyone done it?  are there links to examples?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done it, but the Pro version can read/write databases. See the tutorial:
http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/storing-data.html